# How can I use readline method?

Tags: python

**I have this trivial code:**

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def fma(f):
    f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

fma(current_file)
```

The contents of the txt file is:

```
Hello this is a test.\n
I like cheese and macaroni.\n
I love to drink juice.\n
\n
\n
```

I put the `\n` chars so you know I hit enter in my text editor.

What I want to accomplish is to get back every single line and every `\n` character.

The problem is, when running the script I get nothing back. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it in order to run as I stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty certain what you actually want is **f.readlines**, not **f.readline**.

```
# module start
from __future__ import with_statement # for python 2.5 and earlier

def readfile(path):
    with open(path) as src:
        return src.readlines()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print readfile(sys.argv[1])
# module end
```

Note that I am using the [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) context manager to open your file more efficiently (it does the job of closing the file for you).  In Python 2.6 and later you don't need the fancy import statement at the top to use it, but I have a habit of including it for anyone still using older Python.

Comment: I was reading from here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html  If you look at f.readline() you can see an example below:>>> f.readline()
'This is the first line of the file.\n'
>>> f.readline()
'Second line of the file\n'
>>> f.readline()
''                                                                                                                                         Your reply has been very helpful but returns a list. I wanted to do exactly like the example above f.readlines that returns every line, even though some lines may have only the \n character.

Comment: Yeah, I know ... it's just that it's actually quite unusual to use f.readline ... it's actually a holdover from a long time ago.  In truth, so is f.readlines.  The proper way to do this now is to use the **with open(path, mode) as src** statement (so that you properly handle file closing and avoid memory leaks) coupled with simply iterating over the src object to get at each consecutive line.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for replying so fast and helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your function reads a line, but does nothing with it:

```
def fma(f):
    f.readline()
```

You'd need to return the string that `f.readline()` gives you.  Keep in mind, in the interactive prompt, the last value produced is printed automatically, but that isn't how Python code in a .py file works.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fma(f):
    f.readline()
```

`f.readline()` is a function, it returns a value which is in this case a line from the file, you need to "do" something with that value like:

```
def fma(f):
    print f.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning anything.

```
def fma(f):
    data = f.readline()
    return data
```

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

Answer (score 1):

the script should be as follow:

```
from sys import argv
script, input_file = argv

def fma(f):
    line = f.readline()
    return line

current_file = open(input_file)
print fma(current_file)
```

Comment: How does this help exactly?  Now the value is returned from fma, and then nothing happens with it.

Comment: It was returned into a variable. I now print it, just to pretend I do something more with it ;)